# Unable to get missing termios module. How do I properly get it?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, module

I am attempting to `pip install termios` module and it gives me the following error

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement termios (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for termios

I have attempted this on Python 2.7 and 3.5. On linux.

Answer (score 4):

`termios` is part of the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/termios.html), which means it comes with Python. It provides an interface to the [POSIX terminal calls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) of the underlying OS, which means it only applies on POSIX platforms. So...

1. If you're trying to install it on **Windows**, it will not work because Windows is not a POSIX platform.
2. If you're trying to install it on **Linux**, **macos**, or other POSIX platforms, then there's no need. Just `import termios` in your Python script. If that fails, then your Python install is broken and you should reinstall Python.

Comment: I am on linux. The package says its missing. (I have added that to my first post,thanks for noting it)

Comment: Oh, in that case, "it comes with Python". Just `import termios` in your Python script. If that fails, then your Python install is broken - reinstall Python.

Comment: A whole bunch of things broke x(, But when I reinstalled python. I did notice python-dev was installed and I do believe that is a package that did not come installed unlike python. Could this have been the culprit, If not then it was definitely broken. The only other thing I installed was eclipse from a fresh install. I assume the code ran correctly after and I turned in my hw on time. Although tons of stuff is broken I think ill just fresh install again since all i did add was eclipse and im not sure all that broke. Thanks.