# airflows airflow.operators.python doesnt seem to work

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, airflow

i am trying to import the python operator for my airflow 2.2 in a jupyter notebook, but i get an error
this is what i import
import os
import datetime
import logging

import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

and this is the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'"

Comment: do you run on windows? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54394804/unable-to-get-missing-termios-module-how-do-i-properly-get-it

Answer (score 0):

you need to also import termios

```
import termios
```

Comment: I am on Big Sur and importing termios is successful. Other posts indicate this module may not be available on Windows machines. OP also listed their imports in the post and termios is not included in their list.

Comment: @balderman no it didnt, no module named 'termios'

Comment: are you on a Windows machine? It will only work on unix: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tty.html