# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios' while mounting goole drive in local jupyter notebook (windows 11)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to mount google drive on my local jupyter notebook (Windows 11) using this code:

```
#Mount the google drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

I installed `pip install google-colab`, now when I execute the above command, I am getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\ANEESB~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11196/321285805.py in <module>
      1 #Mount the google drive
----> 2 from google.colab import drive
      3 drive.mount('/content/drive')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\colab\__init__.py in <module>
     21 from google.colab import _installation_commands
     22 from google.colab import _shell_customizations
---> 23 from google.colab import _system_commands
     24 from google.colab import _tensorflow_magics
     25 from google.colab import auth

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\colab\_system_commands.py in <module>
     22 import locale
     23 import os
---> 24 import pty
     25 import select
     26 import signal

~\Anaconda3\lib\pty.py in <module>
     10 import os
     11 import sys
---> 12 import tty
     13 
     14 __all__ = ["openpty","fork","spawn"]

~\Anaconda3\lib\tty.py in <module>
      3 # Author: Steen Lumholt.
      4 
----> 5 from termios import *
      6 
      7 __all__ = ["setraw", "setcbreak"]

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'
```

From what I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54394804/unable-to-get-missing-termios-module-how-do-i-properly-get-it), it seems I cannot install or import `termios` in Windows, but I want to ask, is there a possible solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Correct!

Termios does not ship with the windows distribution of python. Termios is primary for linux/unix terminal operations.

There is a Solution!

> You can use Windows Subsystem for Linux and python3 to run this same script and it should operate perfectly.

1. install wsl2:

press `win` + `x` then `a`

type in:

```
wsl --install
wsl --set-default-version 2
```

2. once you have it setup:

in terminal within your project folder:

```
bash
```

3. You will have to setup your username and password for linux,
   then update and install the necessary dependencies.

```bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install python3-dev
pip3 install google-collab
python3 your_file.py
```

Welcome to Linux on Windows, I love wsl2!

---

***if you dont like this solution*** ...

It might be possible to rewrite the source code of the module to use windows grade terminal actions.

---

***NOTE***

if you want to work on this project in vscode with wsl2,

```
bash
# cd to your project directory
code .
```

this will install vscode for wsl and allows graphical editing and operating on the linux subsystem from windows.